# How BatchSize in Keras works ? LSTM-WithState-Time Series

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm

I am working on Time series problem using LSTM (Stateful) on Keras.

I have 40,000 samples and using batch size of 64 and look back is 7 days. So my tensor shape is (64, 7, 6) 6 is number of features.

My question is when I say batch size = 64; How are samples selected in Keras LSTM. Is it first 64 samples followed by next 64 samples or does it divide samples to 625 windows (40000/64) and send corresponding 64 samples from each window ?

Is this important as I am working on time series problem with state LSTM as forecasting depends on previous days.